# Timber Twig Show Posts Associated with Category

Tags: twig, timber

total noob with Timber and Twig. Im using Advanced Custom Fields with Timber and Twig. In the custom fields I have a field that allows the user to check 3 of any category through a taxonomy field type with the return value of term object.

What I am trying to do is show 3 of any category the user selected and 3 of the associated posts from that category underneath. I have like 14 categories overall.

Would look like this

[image]

In my PHP file I have

```
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('category');
```

In my Twig file:

````

```
 {% for featured_topic in post.get_field('featured_topics')  %}
    <div class="col-md-4 featured-topics-widget">
        <h4>{{featured_topic.name}}</h4>

             <ul>
            {% for topic in topic_post %}
                    <li>{{topic.title}}</li>
            {% endfor %}    
            </ul>

    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

The code above spits out the category title which is fine but Im stuck figuring out how to show the posts that belong to it. any help would be appreciated!!!

**Edit:** I wrote this query (I dont know what Im doing ). It pulls the posts but just duplicates. Sorry putting the question on gitgub. :)

PHP

```
$topic_args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array( 81, 92, 82, 1, 88, 86, 85)
        )
    )
);

$context['topic_post'] = Timber::get_posts($topic_args);
```

TWIG

```
{% for featured_topic in post.get_field('featured_topics')  %}
    <div class="col-md-4 featured-topics-widget">
        <h4>{{featured_topic.name}}</h4>

            <ul>
            {% for cat in topic_post.posts('category') %}
                <li><a href="{{ cat.link }}">{{cat.name}}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}    
            </ul>   

    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is functionality that will...

- Editor creates post and selects 3 categories from an ACF ("featured topics") field on a static front page
- On the front page, a user will see three selected categories
- Under each category the user sees three OTHER posts associated with that category (so 9 posts total)

### home.php

```
$featured_topic_ids = get_field('featured_topics'); 
// you may need to adjust this based on your ACF setup. 
// Basically you're trying to get to an array of category IDs,
// then pass the resulting array to Timber::get_terms();
$context['featured_topics'] = Timber::get_terms($featured_topic_ids);
Timber::render('home.twig', $context);
```

### home.twig

```
{% for ft in featured_topics %}
<h4>{{ ft.name }}</h4>

    {% for catpost in ft.posts(3) %}
         <li><a href="{{ catpost.link }}">{{ catpost.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have the custom field set to an object. For some reason it still doesnt pull. the posts. With your addition to the for statement, I havent added DarkBee's grouped array. Just using the Timber $context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('category');

Comment: Hi Jared. This functionality would be on a static front page. Basically, the admin would go to the homepage edit screen then see a select list of all the categories(we're calling them topics). They can select three categories. once they save and to go to the front-end homepage. 3 topics titles would show and 3 posts would show under each respectively. So yes. 3 categories and 9 posts. Thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: Whoops I meant 3 category titles and just the post titles that are associated with that particular category.

Comment: Jared!!! Thank you so very much. This worked like a charm. I just need to change the custom field to term_id. It grabs the posts!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `grouped` array,

<kbd>PHP</kbd>

```
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('category');
$context['posts_per_category'] = [];
foreach($context['categories'] as $category) $context=['posts_per_category'][$category->ID] = Timber::get_posts('cat='.$category->ID);
```

<kbd>Twig</kbd>

```
{% for cat in categories %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{cat.link}}">{{cat.name}}</a>
        <ul>
            {% for post in posts_per_category[cat.ID] %}
            <li>... Do sthing with post ...</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>       
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```