# How to display all the posts of a specific category

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, categories, posts

I come to you because I have a problem with the creation of a WordPress theme. I am a novice and a little lost.
Let me explain :

I have a page that displays the title of each category of my site. I would like that when the customer clicks on a category, it is directed to another page containing all the articles contained in this same category (Knowing that there are only photos in the articles, no text).
On the WordPress codex, I found some info but that does not work, or so what is more likely, I missed something ..
Small precision, I work with Timber to use twig files for the view.

```html
Category.twig
{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
<li>{{ post.content }}</li>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

In fact, the problem is that it displays all the messages I have, not just the posts in the category I clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'cat' => ( get_queried_object() )->term_id
);

$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts($args);

Timber::render('category.twig', $context);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create a taxonomy-{texonomy_name}.php in your theme and you can use wp_query loop inside theme to view all posts of your texonomy term.

```
<?php 
 if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_title();
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hi ! It will work if i just want one category. But i want to do this with all category without create 200 taxonomy_name.php

Answer (score 0):

Editor creates post and selects 3 categories from an ACF ("featured topics") field on a static front page
On the front page, a user will see three selected categories
Under each category the user sees three OTHER posts associated with that category (so 9 posts total)

**php file**

$featured_topic_ids = get_field('featured_topics');

Timber::get_terms();

$context['featured_topics'] = Timber::get_terms($featured_topic_ids);

Timber::render('home.twig', $context);

**twig file**
{% for ft in featured_topics %}

{{ ft.name }}

```
{% for catpost in ft.posts(3) %}
     <li><a href="{{ catpost.link }}">{{ catpost.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

You can follow this link
[Timber Twig Show Posts Associated with Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570245/timber-twig-show-posts-associated-with-category) .